# Automation of testing using JUnit

Tags: java, junit

i am trying to automate manual testing of modules in my project. We are dealing with IBM Websphere Message queue software. We have a trigger component written in core java which when executed polls for availability of message in the configured queue. Its an indefinite while loop that keeps the trigger component running. I have written test cases in JUnit to put message in the queue and now will i be able to start/stop the trigger component on demand? Invoking the trigger component keeps it running and i am not getting the control back to check the expected output. If i start it in thread then the log files to which the trigger component is supposed to update when processing the message is not getting updated. How can i resolve this situation.
Your suggestion and directions is highly appreciated. 
Thanks,
-Vijay

Answer (score 2):

I would look at moving your manual build to a scripted build using something like Apache Ant and using the junit support, see http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html.

Once you have your tests which you can run via Ant, you can integrate into a continuous integration container like Hudson (hudson-ci.org) and get it to schedule a build run on a timer.  You can also schedule to run on a code check-in.

For more on continuous integration take a look at Martin Fowler's article, http://martinfowler.com/articles/continuousIntegration.html.